PowerShell version anomalies
The script at the end of the post seems to have different problems based on the machine it is running on and the Version of PowerShell (Windows vs Core). Here is the digest of results with all pertinent machine/OS/PS information.
Edition:   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro 64-bit
Version:   2009 23H2
Build:     22631.3593 (May Updates)
Installed: 2/29/2024 10:20

Dell XPS 8920 i7-7700 32Gb DDR4 Dual Channel

Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully 
qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name 
must be less than 248 characters.
At G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\File Manipulation\Get-WinSettingsAppsV3.ps1:108 char:13
+ $CtrlObjs = Get-ChildItem @GCIArgs |
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.PathTooLongException,Microsoft.PowerSh 
   ell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
The variable '$CtrlObjs' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\File Manipulation\Get-WinSettingsAppsV3.ps1:113 char:16
+ For ($Cntr = $($CtrlObjs.count - 1); $Cntr -ge 0; $Cntr--) {
+                ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CtrlObjs:String) [], RuntimeE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the 
collection.
Parameter name: index
At G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\File Manipulation\Get-WinSettingsAppsV3.ps1:132 char:1
+ [Void]$FinalList.Add(($SettingObjs[0]))
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentOutOfRangeExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
 
Program Vers   : 3.0
Powershell Vers: 5.1.22621.2506  (ISE)
Run Time       : 00:23
Setting Pgms   : 0

--------------------------------------------

Program Vers   : 3.0
Powershell Vers: 5.1.22621.2506  (CLI)
Run Time       : 00:41
Setting Pgms   : 43

Name                       Path
----                       ----
appwiz.cpl                 C:\Windows\System32
bthprops.cpl               C:\Windows\System32
                ...
WF.msc                     C:\Windows\System32\en-US
WmiMgmt.msc                C:\Windows\System32

-----------------------------------------------

Program Vers   : 3.0
Powershell Vers: 7.4.2
Run Time       : 26:22
Setting Pgms   : 43

Name                       Path
----                       ----
appwiz.cpl                 C:\Windows\System32
bthprops.cpl               C:\Windows\System32
...
WF.msc                     C:\Windows\System32
WmiMgmt.msc                C:\Windows\System32

===================================================

MinsiForum UM790 Pro Ryzen 7940HS 32Gb DDR5 Dual Channel

Edition:   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro 64-bit
Version:   2009 23H2
Build:     22631.3593 (May Updates)

Program Vers   : 3.0
Powershell Vers: 5.1.22621.2506  (ISE)
Run Time       : 00:34
Setting Pgms   : 41

Name                       Path                                           
----                       ----                                           
appwiz.cpl                 C:\Windows\System32                            
bthprops.cpl               C:\Windows\System32                            
                ...                      
WF.msc                     C:\Windows\System32\en-US                      
WmiMgmt.msc                C:\Windows\System32                          

-----------------------------------------------------

Program Vers   : 3.0
Powershell Vers: 5.1.22621.2506  (CLI)
Run Time       : 00:22
Setting Pgms   : 41

Name                       Path
----                       ----
appwiz.cpl                 C:\Windows\System32
bthprops.cpl               C:\Windows\System32
              ...
WF.msc                     C:\Windows\System32
WmiMgmt.msc                C:\Windows\System32\en-US

-----------------------------------------------------

Program Vers   : 3.0
Powershell Vers: 7.4.2
Run Time       : 22:43
Setting Pgms   : 41

Name                       Path
----                       ----
appwiz.cpl                 C:\Windows\System32
bthprops.cpl               C:\Windows\System32
               ,,,
WF.msc                     C:\Windows\System32\en-US
WmiMgmt.msc                C:\Windows\System32

Here's the code:


Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [Switch] $Report
)

Function Get-AdminStatus {

  $identity =
     [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
  $principal =
     New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $identity

  If (-NOT ($principal.IsInRole(
      [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)))
    {"User"}
  Else
    {"Administrator"}

} #End Function -----------  Get-AdminStatus ------------------


#------------------------ Main Program ------------------------

Clear-Host

$PgmVers = [Version]"3.0"
$Message = ""
$Title   = ""

Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"

$Top =
 new-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -property @{Topmost=$true}

$TermMsg = {
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Top, $Message, $Title,
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK ,
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)}


If ( (Get-AdminStatus) -eq "User") {
  $Message =
     "Program REQUIRES Powershell to be run`n" +
      "as Administrator!"
  $Title  = "Administrator Access REQUIRED...Terminating!"
  $Button = "OK"
  $Icon   = "Error"
  $Null   = & $TermMsg
  Exit
}

$RunStartTime = Get-Date

# Create lists to hold .cpl & .msc files
$SettingObjs = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]
$FinalList   = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]

$GCIArgs = @{Path        = "C:\"
             Recurse     = $True
             File        = $True
             Include     = "*.cpl","*.msc"
             ErrorAction = "SilentlyContinue"
            }
$CtrlObjs = Get-ChildItem @GCIArgs | 
            Sort-Object Extension,Name -Descending
 
# Loop through each Array Element and weed out copies

For ($Cntr = $($CtrlObjs.count - 1); $Cntr -ge 0; $Cntr--) {

   $TestVal = ($CtrlObjs[$Cntr].DirectoryName)

   If ($TestVal -NotMatch 
        "SysWOW64|WinSxS|DriverStore|Distribution") {

     [Void]$SettingObjs.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $($CtrlObjs[$($Cntr)].Name)
            Path = $($CtrlObjs[$($Cntr)].DirectoryName)
            Ext  = $($CtrlObjs[$($Cntr)].Extension)
           }) 

   } #End If

}    #End For

#Remove Duplicates from the list

[Void]$FinalList.Add(($SettingObjs[0]))

For ($Cntr = 1; $Cntr -lt $SettingObjs.Count; $Cntr++) {

   If (-Not ($SettingObjs[$($Cntr-1)].Name -eq 
            ($SettingObjs[$($Cntr)].Name))) {
    [Void]$FinalList.Add(($SettingObjs[$($Cntr)]))
   }

}

$RunTime = ((Get-Date) - $RunStartTIme)

#Generate Report Content Variable
  $RptCont =
    "Program Vers   : $PgmVers`n"                       +
    "Powershell Vers: $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)`n"   +
    "$("Run Time       : {0:mm}:{0:ss}" -f $RunTime)`n" + 
    "Setting Pgms   : $($FInalList.count)" | Out-String
  $RptCont += $FinalList | FT -Property Name, Path |
     Out-String

If ($Report.IsPresent) {

$ReportFile =
  "$([environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments"))\" +
  "Windows Setting Pgms Output.txt"

  $RptCont > $ReportFile

}
Else { 
  $RptCont
}

Comment based help stripped out as post is already too long.
So my actual questions:

Why does Windows PS ISE run fine on the UM790Pro and produce errors on the Dell XPS8920?
Why does PS Core run exponentially longer than Windows PS?

